# UiApp createServerHandler parameter arguments

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Here is the output from a button callback, as you can see it returns a reference to the picker control which is included in the grid control that they were both added to:

```
[13-09-06 21:59:07:575 ICT] {clientY=83, clientX=100, eventType=click, ctrl=false, meta=false, source=Today, button=1, alt=false, picker=Sat Sep 07 00:00:00 GMT+07:00 2013, screenY=399, screenX=649, y=16, shift=false, x=28}
```

Here is the code used to hook it all up:

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(600).setHeight(400);
var submitHandler = app.createServerHandler('eventFormData_Save_');
var dateBtnsHandler = app.createServerHandler('eventDateBtns_');

// create panels
var vPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttributes(css.body);
var sPanel = app.createScrollPanel().setId('sPanel');

// add vPanel to sPanel
sPanel.add(vPanel);

var dToday = getWholeDay(new Date());  

var oDateGrid = app.createGrid(3,3);
var oBtnPrev = app.createButton('< Prev').setId('Prev');
var oBtnNext = app.createButton('Next >').setId('Next');
var oBtnToday = app.createButton('Today').setId('Today').setWidth('100');

var oTxtOldDate = app.createTextBox().setId('pickerOldDate').setWidth('50');    
var oPickerLabel = app.createLabel('Selected Date:',false).setId('pickerLabel');        
var oPicker = app.createDateBox().setId("picker").setName("picker").setWidth('100')
.setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.DATE_SHORT)
.setValue(dToday).setFocus(true);


oDateGrid.setWidget(0,1,oPickerLabel);
oDateGrid.setWidget(1,0,oBtnPrev).setWidget(1,1,oPicker).setWidget(1,2,oBtnNext);
oDateGrid.setWidget(2,0,oTxtOldDate).setWidget(2,1,oBtnToday);

dateBtnsHandler.addCallbackElement(oDateGrid);
//dateBtnsHandler.addCallbackElement(oTxtOldDate);//tried adding the txtbox explicitly to no effect

oBtnPrev.addClickHandler(outgoingClientHandler).addClickHandler(dateBtnsHandler);        
oBtnNext.addClickHandler(outgoingClientHandler).addClickHandler(dateBtnsHandler);        
oBtnToday.addClickHandler(outgoingClientHandler).addClickHandler(dateBtnsHandler);       
oPicker.addValueChangeHandler(outgoingClientHandler).addValueChangeHandler(dateBtnsHandler);
oTxtOldDate.addValueChangeHandler(dateBtnsHandler);

app.add(oDateGrid);
```

it's not all the code as it rambles a bit and shouldn't be relevant, while some of what's there relates to later elements - just let me know if it's not clear!

Problem arises when trying to reference the pickerOldDate within the same callback function as for the buttons

```
{source=picker, eventType=valuechange, picker=Sat Sep 07 00:00:00 GMT+07:00 2013}
```

So I'm not sure what to be surprised by, the picker being in the button callback parameter, or the pickerOldDate not being in the picker callback parameter. Any advice?

BTW: the point (if it's not clear) is to retain an 'OldValue' for the picker in case users pick a date in the future (not allowed), I need to return the picker value to the one before the callback was invoked. If I've missed a trick in engineering this outcome, I'm happy to go another route - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to assign the name of any object you hope will appear in the callback, I had only set the Id and it cost me a few hours - Documentation may not be Google's strong point :)

```
var oTxtOldDate = app.createTextBox().setId('pickerOldDate').setName('pickerOldDate').setWidth('50');
```

Hope this helps someone else